# Force org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity.ok to keep Pascal-case json

Tags: java, spring

I have a ResponseEntity-returning Rest Service that has a HashMap that contains as value the List<> returned from a findAll() JPA operation.

```java
@GetMapping("/users")
public ResponseEntity getUsers() {

  List<Users> users = userRepository.findAll();
  var model = new HashMap<>();
  model.put("data",users);

  return ok(model);
}
```

The HashMap's keys are in Pascal-case format (like "UserMail"), but when the rest service returns, it converts the keys to camel-case ("userMail"). Is there a way to prevent it so it keeps the original format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to enforce all properties under Users to Pascal-case format. You can try to apply PropertyNamingStrategy to the class

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class)
Class Users {
   ...
}
```